# Django Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found Error

Tags: django

I am receiving this error

```
Reverse for 'option' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

while I am rendering my option page. The option page is the last page in a 3 part workstream. The first 2 pages work fine. I am not sure why nothing is rendering. My code is below:

**views.py**

```
def drui_index(request):
  disease_list = Disease.objects.all()
  context = {'disease_list':disease_list, 'hide_breadcrumb': hide_breadcrumb}
  return render(request, 'drui_index.html', context)


def drui(request, disease_id):
  disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)  

  if request.method == "POST":
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=disease)

      if indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid():
         indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('option', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))

  else:
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(instance=disease)

  return render(request, 'drui.html', {'disease':disease, 'indicatorInlineFormSet': indicatorInlineFormSet})


def option(request, disease_id):

     disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)

     if request.method == "POST":
         optionInlineFormSet = OptionFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=disease, prefix='option')
         outcomeInlineFormSet = OutcomeFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=disease, prefix='outcome')


        if optionInlineFormSet.is_valid() and outcomeInlineFormSet.is_valid:
           optionInlineFormSet.save()
           outcomeInlineFormSet.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('splash', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))

    else:
        optionInlineFormSet = OptionFormSet(instance=disease,prefix='option')  
        outcomeInlineFormSet = OutcomeFormSet(instance=disease,prefix='outcome')

   return render(request, 'option.html', {'optionInlineFormSet': optionInlineFormSet, 'outcomeInlineFormSet': outcomeInlineFormSet})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^drui_index/$', 'Physician_UI.views.drui_index', name='drui_index'),
url(r'^drui_index/(?P<disease_id>\d+)/$', 'Physician_UI.views.drui', name='drui'),
url(r'^drui_index/(?P<disease_id>\d+)/option/$', 'Physician_UI.views.option', name='option'),
```

**HTML drui_index.html**

```
{% load url from future %}
<form class="disease_form" action="{% url "drui_index" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

**HTML drui.html**

```
{% load url from future %}
<form class="disease_form" action="{% url "drui" disease.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

**HTML option.html**

```
 {% load url from future %}
 <form class="option_form" action="{% url "option" disease.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

As I mentioned before, the first 2 pages (drui_index, and drui) work fine but option.html does not. I included most of the code just in case I'm passing information in the wrong way.

I am using django 1.4

Comment: This is your 3rd question of same type. Haven't you learned from your old mistakes?

Comment: I still can't figure it out Aamir. I did a work around for the first 2 questions where I didn't call in a form for the index. And I got it working for the first 2 but I still can't seem to figure out why the reverse doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry andrewdotn, this isn't a duplicate. The solution in the link above isn't working for the problem here. Let me know if you see anything that stands out. Or if you can explain to me on a high-level what may be the problem. I've been struggling with this type of problem all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `disease` object in context in your `option` view. You are not passing `disease` object in context and in template you are using `disease.id` hence the error.

```
return render(request, 'option.html',
    {'optionInlineFormSet': optionInlineFormSet,
    'outcomeInlineFormSet': outcomeInlineFormSet,
    'disease': disease})
```

Comment: Thanks aamir, i just figured that out while looking at the code. Sorry for the repeated similar questions. Just started with django and i've been programming all day. I can't really think straight...But i appreciate your help